# Determining whether a function has an image that is the entire set of reals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am doing a textbook exercise that asks me to determine whether the function

$$h(x)= \begin{cases}
        x & \text{if $x\ge0$}\\
       -x & \text{if $x\lt0$}
\end{cases}
$$

has an image that is the entire set of real numbers.
Looking at the function I assume that it is equivalent to $h(x)=x$ and therefore the answer is that the image does contain the entire set of reals. However, the answer says that this is incorrect. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: What value of $x$ solves $f(x)=-1$?

Comment: Right. Got it. All the negative x's have positive outputs, so the function can only have an image consisting of positive real numbers. Thanks.

Comment: Note that $h$ is simply the absolute value function.

Comment: The range of the function $h(x) = |x|$ is the set $[0, \infty) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \geq 0\}$ of non-negative real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $x<0$, then $-x>0$. What can you now say about $h(x)$ if $x<0$ (positive or negative)?